# Calculating the intersection point of a hyperbola and a line

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have a fully automated display program in which a hyperbola (being defined as $\frac{(y-k)^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2} = 1$ or $y=\sqrt{a^2(\frac{x^2}{b^2}+1)}+k$ because I only care about the upper curve is intersecting with a straight line $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ and I want to find the $x$ coordinate where they intersect. The issue is that pretty much everything is automated, so all the constants $a$, $b$, $k$, $y_1$, $m$, and $x_1$ all need to remain as variables. My algebra skills are not nearly refined enough to solve for $x$ in the equation $\sqrt{a^2(\frac{x^2}{b^2}+1)}+k = m(x-x_1)+y_1$, so if anybody can help out, or find an easier way to calculate the intersection, I'd appreciate it tons.

Answer (score 2):

First move $k$ to the right:
$$\sqrt{a^2 \left(\frac{x^2}{b^2}+1 \right)} = m(x-x_1)+(y_1-k)$$

and then square both sides:
$$a^2 \left(\frac{x^2}{b^2} + 1 \right) = m^2 (x - x_1)^2 + 2m(x - x_1)(y_1 - k) + (y_1)^2 - 2y_1k +k^2$$
$$\implies \frac{a^2}{b^2} x^2 + a^2 = \left(m^2 x^2 - 2m^2 x_1 x + m^2(x_1)^2 \right) + \left(2m(y_1 - k)x - 2m(y_1 - k)x_1 \right) + (y_1)^2 - 2y_1k +k^2$$

and now rearrange to form a quadratic equation:
$$\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2} - m^2 \right)x^2 + \left(2m^2x_1 - 2m(y_1 - k)\right)x + \left(a^2 - m^2 (x_1)^2+2m(y_1 - k)x_1 - (y_1)^2 + 2y_1k-k^2 \right) = 0$$

From here, the exact value of $x$ can be found using the quadratic formula.

Comment: You do get two solutions cause of squaring (the other solution is to the equation LHS = -RHS) so you have to substitute these solutions back into the original equation to find the right value of x.